# Movie featuring a robot/cyborg with a flying saucer-like head and a futuristic tank

Tags: story-identification, movie, robots

Only images I have left in my head is that there was a robot/cyborg in the movie that had a flying saucer-like head. Also, another scene is like a futuristic tank that was shooting huge bullets.

That is pretty much everything that I remember. Also, the time I saw it was between 1989-1992, not sure 100%, but the movie plot was a war between robots or something like that.

Comment: Could this be the Lost in Space remake? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tsmacmhdrUs

Comment: Do you mean the robot's head *looks* like a flying saucer? It helps to be more clear about that sort of thing.

Comment: @Nu'Daq - Like this, presumably; https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/de/Lost_in_Space_Jonathan_Harris_%26_Robot_1967.jpg

Comment: In "Robot wars" there are tank-like robots and flat-head robots https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0107979/

Comment: Was if live action or animated? Was it at the cinema, on TV or on VHS?